# Changing table column to generated date - syntax problem

Tags: mysql

I'd like to change a column from manual input of an expiry date to a generated column based on 'joined' which contains the current date when a membership form was submitted and 'duration' which contains the length of membership in years (1 or 5)
I've hunted around but can't find a similar case so I wondered if anyone could help out?

Current query I'm using is:

```
ALTER TABLE `rsf96104_rsf_members`.`members` 
CHANGE COLUMN `renewal_date` `renewal_date` DATE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (DATE_ADD( `joined` +  INTERVAL `duration` YEAR)) STORED ;
```

Also tried with the `'+'` replaced by `','`

Comment: Generated columns are a feature which were only introduced in MySQL 5.7.  Your version 5.6 does not support them.  I suggest upgrading to MySQL 8.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realised that, I'll have to talk to our host on the subject